# pyspark mathematical computation in a dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have extracted a Dataframe from a larger Dataframe, and now I need to do simple computation like addition and division in dataframe.
sample dataframe is like.

item   counts

z      23156

x      15462

What I need to do is to divide x by sum of x and z

for example

value=  x/x+z

Answer (score 2):

You must compute the sum of x and first then divide x by sum(x) + sum(y)

for example:

Table 1(original table):

> x   z
>
> 1   2
>
> 3   4

Table 2 (Aggregated table):

```
table2 = sqlCtx.sql("select sum(x) + sum(z) as sum_xz")
table2.registerTempTable("table2")
```

> sum_xz
>
> 10

Then join both table and divide

```
table3 = sqlCtx.sql("select a.x / bs.um_xz from table1 a join table2 b")
```

For your reference.